# How to generate random numbers from density function if it's known that if $X_i$ are iid and $X_i \sim F$, then $F(x_i) \sim U[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning, problem-solving

The given density function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\phi(x, 0, 1) + \frac{1}{10}\sum^4_{j=0}\phi(x; (j/2)-1, 1/10) $$
where $\phi$ is normal distribution.

```
f <- function(x){
  dnorm(x)/2 +
    dnorm(x,- 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 1/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 2/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 3/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 4/2 - 1, 1/10)/10
}
```

It is known that if random variables $X_i$ are iid, and $X_i \sim F$, then $F(X_i)\sim U[0,1]$
I tried to define the cumulative function:

```
F <- function(x){integrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = x)}$value
```

And then to find zeroes of function $F(x)-\text{runif}(x)$

```
zeros <- function(x){uniroot(F(x)-runif(x), c(-10,10))}
```

But the program R gives me an error:

```
Error in uniroot(F(x) - runif(x), c(-10, 10)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Anyway, I am at loss as to the way, this problem could be possibly solved. Does anybody got any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show how you are calling the function zeros, so I am not sure how to explain why you get this error.  Probably, when you are calling zeros, it tries to evaluate runif(x) where x is a number between 0 and 1 and that is the source of the problem.

Try this.

```
f <- function(x){
  dnorm(x)/2 +
    dnorm(x,- 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 1/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 2/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 3/2 - 1, 1/10)/10 +
    dnorm(x, 4/2 - 1, 1/10)/10
}
integrate(f,lower=-Inf,upper = Inf)
F <- function(x){integrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = x)}$value
Finv <- function(t) uniroot(function(x,t) F(x)-t,c(-10,10),t=t)$root
(u=runif(1))
F(Finv(u))
Finv(F(u))
```

This verifies that Finv is the inverse of F.
Then, you can simulate a random variable with distribution $F$ by using Finv(runf(1)).

Comment: The problem is that I cannot generate more than one number, but I need 1000. As soon as I put $u=runif(50)$ it gives the same error.

Comment: that's because runif is not vectorized. Let me work on it for a few minutes.

Comment: try Vectorize(Finv)(runif(50))

Comment: Can you explain why do we take uniroot of $F(x)-t$?

Comment: @user You want F(x)=t so Finv(t)=x

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if you have a mixture with six different densities, mixing coefficients $\pi_k$ where $\pi_1 = 1/2$ and the other five are $1/10$. What you might want to do to generate $X$ is to select one of these densities at random, using these probabilities, then generate $X$ from that one:

1. Select $i$ from $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ with probabilities
   $\{1/2, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10 \}$.
2. Return $X$ from $f_i$.